# Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'filter')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, react-hooks, typeerror

I am doing a small react drop dowm task. My project is smoothly running in google crome. But in MS explorer it's showing an error. Then I deploy it in live server, it's not also running there. I cannot not solve this error (Cannot read properties of null (reading 'filter')) . Please help!!

**Error Image**: [Raw code in compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVIIU.png)
[Error in browser inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ycBc.png)

I tried to debug it for many times but cannot solve. It's wired error. Running in crome but giving error in explorer and live site. I am expecting someone would help me to find the error in code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: @Asif Mahmud, please share your code block.

Comment: Having said that... If `tasks.filter()` produces that error then clearly `tasks` is `null`.  What value do you expect `tasks` to have and why?  Are you asking how to check if a variable is `null`?  Something else?  "How to solve the error" depends on what you're trying to do, whether you want to modify the code to handle a `null` value or whether you want to investigate why the value is `null` when it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid getting a "TypeError: filter is not a function" error in JavaScript when filtering an array, you can use the `?` operator. The `?` operator is used to handle optional values, such as when you're not sure if an array exists or has a value. By using the `?` operator after the array name (e.g. `items?.filter()`), you're essentially saying "if `items` is not null or undefined, then call the `filter()` method on it".

If `items` is indeed null or undefined, then the `filter()` method won't be called and no error will be thrown. This is a helpful way to handle optional values in JavaScript and can help prevent errors in your code.